# How do I make an specific rating star widget with CSS?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm working on a rating stars field for a little form, but I can't change the HTML structure because it's created using Gravity Forms, so I just can "manipulate" it with CSS.

The form is structured as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" value="5">
        <label>5/label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" value="4">
        <label>4</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        ...
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've been using [this example](http://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/vlpkh) but now, with this structure, the `[input/label]` elements are not siblings of the other `[input/label]` elements.

How can I make it work without modifying the markup?

Thanks!

Comment: If no other choice, you could append after this part of form with JS the old form you used, , hide the regluar part, and insert the values of the nice form into the hidden not nice via JS.

Comment: Can you add class to the li or ul elements as seen in the example ? or you just want to fully manipulate this structure with css ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use that html structure, you can't do it without using javascript. I'm assuming you cant edit the current elements either (if you can, do so) so i have including that in the javascript as well, adding attributes as required.

http://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/BjyegJ

Here I've wrapped your list in a `div` with class `.rating`

Then i update the inputs and labels with the required attributes to emulate the example you have in your comment. Then i use jquerys `replaceWith` function to remove the list structure and return only the `inputs` and `labels`, wrapped in the `.ratings` div.

```
$(".rating ul li").each(function(i){
  $("input", this).attr({
    "id" : "star"+parseInt(5-i),
    "name" : "rating"
  });
  $("label", this).attr({
    "class": "full",
    "for" : "star"+parseInt(5-i),
    "title" : "Awesome - "+parseInt(5-i)+" stars"
  });
});
replaceIt();
function replaceIt() {
  $(".rating ul").replaceWith(function() {
    return $('input, label', this);
  });
}
```

Comment: @overflowchart Awesome.